# List Lookup Performance - Does returning the last element of a list have to scan through the whole list?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
myDict = {
    'title': 'a nice title',
    'nice_list': [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7,...,99999],
    'nice_lists_last_item': 99999,
}
```

I only want to append an item to `nice_list` if it is larger than the final item.

What is quicker:

1. Using: `if new_element > nice_list[-1]`

or

1. Using: `if new_element > nice_lists_last_item`

Does method 1 have to scan through the whole list (and/or put all of `nice_list` into memory each time) to find that item? Which is quicker? (bearing in mind I intend to do a few billion of these comparisons?)

Method 2 would store the last element as its own distinct dict entry, so is that faster?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "a few billion of these" is going to take a few seconds (or maybe a few dozen seconds) for _any_ implementation you come up with. And there's a good chance that the difference between running the same code in Python 2.7 vs. 3.3 or CPython vs. PyPy or 32-bit vs. 64-bit etc. will be bigger than the difference between your implementations. So, are you sure this is worth micro-optimizing?

Comment: Python lists are dynamic arrays no, they can do that in O(1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in doubt, test:

```
>>> %timeit if 1 > myDict['nice_list'][-1]: 0
10000000 loops, best of 3: 110 ns per loop
>>> %timeit if 1 > myDict['nice_lists_last_item']: 0
10000000 loops, best of 3: 68.8 ns per loop
>>> nice_list = myDict['nice_list']
>>> %timeit if 1 > nice_list[-1]: 0
10000000 loops, best of 3: 62.6 ns per loop
>>> nice_lists_last_item = myDict['nice_lists_last_item']
>>> %timeit if 1 > nice_lists_last_item: 0                      
10000000 loops, best of 3: 43.4 ns per loop
```

As you can see, accessing the dictionary value directly is faster than accessing the list from the dictionary and then accessing its last value. But accessing the last value of the list directly is faster. This should be no surprise; Python lists know their own length and are implemented in memory as arrays, so finding the last item is as simple as subtracting 1 from the length and doing pointer arithmetic. Accessing dictionary keys is a bit slower because of the overhead of collision detection; but it's only slower by a few nanoseconds. And finally, if you really want to save a few more nanoseconds, you could store the last value in its own value.

The biggest slowdown comes when you do *both*.

Comment: It's worth adding in the cost of doing neither: `last_item = nice_list[-1]` then `%timeit if 1 > last_time: 0`. When I run this, I get 56.6ns, vs. 63.6ns for the dict lookup! So, even with the most trivial example you could come up with, we're spending more than 90% of our time on unrelated overhead. Which means there is almost certainly no point in trying to optimize this in the first place.

Comment: Also, trying to test this in PyPy… I get warnings about the compiler taking longer than the actual code, and if I run it repeatedly until that stops, the time ends up at 2.05ns per loop.

Comment: By the way, these comments are intended to add to the point of this answer ("When in doubt, test", and "… but it's only slower by a few nanoseconds"), not to argue against it or anything. It's a great answer as-is, I just thought more information might make it even better.

Comment: For completeness, though, you should really be comparing the direct `nice_list[-1]` check (your third example) with a direct check on a stored value, e.g., `1 > nice_lists_last_item`.  It's true that removing the dict lookup will speed things up, but removing the dict will speed *everything* up, so storing the last value separately will still be faster (and it is, when I test it).  Your last comparison is apples-and-oranges to the first two.  Also, you may or may not be able to remove the dict (e.g., if you have a lot of them, you can't just dump them all into the global namespace).

Comment: Good point, BrenBarn & abarnert, thanks. (Also, re: PyPy -- I probably shouldn't be surprised but -- wow!)

Answer (score 4):

Getting an item from a list is O(1) as noted [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).  Even so, storing the value explicitly will still be faster, because no matter how fast the lookup is, it's still going to be slower than not doing a lookup at all.  (However, if you store the value explicitly, you'll have to update it when you add a new item to the list; whether the combined cost if updating it and checking it is more than the cost of grabbing the last item every time is something you'll have to benchmark yourself; it will likely depend on how often you wind up actually appending a new item.)

Note that there is no question of "putting all of `nice_list` into memory".  If you have a dict with a list in it, that entire list is already in memory.  Looking up a value in it won't cause it to take up any more memory, but if you have billions of these lists, you will run out of memory before you even try to look anything up, because just creating the lists will use up too much memory.

Answer (score 1):

In CPython, the answer is probably no. list is implemented using dynamic arrays.

Comment: The answer to "which is quicker" is "no"?

Comment: @abarnert - the answer to "Does method 1 have to scan through the whole list (and/or put all of nice_list into memory each time) to find that item?" is definitely "no". 
in some sense, so is the answer to "which is quicker", as was pointed out by senderle.

Comment: I see. I guess when someone asks 7 different questions in one, it's kind of hard to give a one-word answer without confusing people. :)